# How can I convert this form_tag form into a form_for form in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been trying to figure out how to write a form_for version of this form for my passwords_controller. I have resources :passwords in my routes.rb file. I looked at my login form and even though it doesn't really access the model I still used form_for and it worked. I tried the same thing and I keep getting issues so I'm using the code below and that's working but would really like to know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<%= form_tag passwords_path, :method => :post do %>
  <div id="#emailFieldJoin">
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "Email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please define "I keep getting issues." Also, posting the code that is working is OK, but it's more useful to also post the code that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by studying my sessions_controller and associated view file.

Basically:

```
  <%= form_for :password_reset, :url => passwords_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>      
  <%= f.submit "Reset Password", :disable_with => 'Log In'%>
  <% end %>
```

The first argument is a symbol of your choice.

I used params[:password_reset][:email] to grab these params from my view in my passwords controller.
So the important thing is the first argument passed to the form_for helper.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<%= form_for @password do |f| %>
  <div id="#emailFieldJoin">
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Reset Password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

So in your controller you should create a `@password` object, probably fill the `email` from the `params` and then render this form.

Hope this helps.